# How to connect Tableau to Presto which is in Hortonworks sandox (Azure)?

Tags: tableau-api, presto, hortonworks-sandbox

I've installed and configured presto-server on Hortonworks sandbox (on Azure) and I can access Hive, mysql etc using presto CLI.
When I tried to connect Presto using web connector API in Tableau, It could not able to connect the presto server.
If anyone knows the solution please let me know.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add a new inbound security rule with the respective port number in the network security group (Azure).